# STL map, using iterators and pointers of classes

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I am having trouble accessing data inside a map using an iterator. I want to return all of the  values inserted into the map by using an iterator. However, when I use the iterator, it doesn't acknowledge any of the members in the instance of the class it has been past into.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int numberOfVertices;
    char filename[30];
    string tmp;

    //the class the holds the graph
    map<string, MapVertex*> mapGraph;

    //input the filename
    cout << "Input the filename of the graph: ";
    cin >> filename;
    inputFile.open(filename);

    if (inputFile.good())
    {
        inputFile >> numberOfVertices;
        inputFile.ignore();

        for (int count = 0; count < numberOfVertices; count++)
        {
            getline(inputFile, tmp);
            cout << "COUNT: " << count << "  VALUE: " << tmp << endl;

            MapVertex tmpVert;
            tmpVert.setText(tmp);
            mapGraph[tmp]=&tmpVert;
        }

        string a;
        string connectTo[2];

        while (!inputFile.eof())
        {

            //connectTo[0] and connectTo[1] are two strings that are behaving as keys

            MapVertex* pointTo;
            pointTo = mapGraph[connectTo[0]];
            pointTo->addNeighbor(mapGraph[connectTo[1]]);
            //map.find(connectTo[0]).addNeighbor(map.find(connectTo[1]));
            //cout << connectTo[0] << "," << connectTo[1] << endl;
        }

        map<string,MapVertex*>::iterator it;
        for (it=mapGraph.begin(); it!=mapGraph.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << it->getText() << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
\lab12\main.cpp||In function `int main()':|
\lab12\main.cpp|69|error: 'struct std::pair<const std::string, MapVertex*>'
                           has no member named 'getText'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

There is an access member in my MapVertex class called getText() which returns the data that is inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the compiler error, you need to do `it->second->getText()` as the `*iterator` is a `pair<string, MapVertex*>`. But there are other problems in your code. While inserting into the map, you are inserting the address of a local variable into it. This address will be invalid by the time you try to iterate the map using `for` loop. I would suggest you to declare the map as `std::map<string, MyVertex>` so that when you insert into the map a *copy* of the MyVertex is inserted into map.

Comment: I definitely see what's going on now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`tmpVert` is the problem. Look, you create it on the stack. It is destroyed at the end of each `for` loop.

It Is Destroyed.

So, your `mapGraph` is holding pointers to objects that don't exist.

Comment: Perhaps I was clumsy using my pointers. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

```
'struct std::pair' has no member named 'getText'
```

means that what the iterator returns is std::pair, not your object directly; the first element of the pair is the key, the second the value, so you need to get the value, and then call the method: `it->second->method()`.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to access that data, and that definitely helped out too. Thanks!